# How do you access wordpress established shortcode attributes from a class in an AJAX call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have developed a shortcode that initially outputs some HTML then on page load does an AJAX call to load additional content.

The initial part is working fine, and technically I am getting a response, but I do not seem to be able to get content based on the custom shortcode parameters.

Here is a basic version of my code:

The PHP

```
<?php

/**
 * Class AjaxShortcode
 */
class AjaxShortcode {

    public $atts;

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAtts() {
        return $this->atts;
    }

    /**
     * @param $atts
     */
    public function setAtts( $atts ) {
        $this->atts = $atts;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        add_shortcode( 'ajax_test', [ $this, 'output' ] );

        add_action( "wp_ajax_ajax_test", [ $this, 'ajaxDelayed' ] );
        add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_test", [ $this, 'ajaxDelayed' ] );
    }

    public function enqueueDelayScripts($atts) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_test_js', plugins_url( '/js/ajax.js', dirname(__FILE__)), [], filemtime( plugin_dir_path( dirname(__FILE__)) .'js/ajax.js' ) );
        $data = [
            'ajax_url'     => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        ];
        foreach ($atts as $key => $att) {
            $data[$key] = $att;
        }
        wp_localize_script( 'ajax_test_js', 'data', $data );

    }


    /**
     * @param $atts
     * @return string
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function output( $atts ) {
        $atts = shortcode_atts( [
            'att_1'       => '',
            'att_2'       => 'true',
            'att_3'       => 1000
        ], $atts, 'ajax_test' );
        $this->enqueueDelayScripts($atts);
        $this->setAtts($atts);

        echo '<h1>Initial Output</h1>';
    }

    /**
     * @param $atts
     * @return array 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function ajaxDelayedGetEvents($atts) {
        $atts = $this->getAtts();    

        $html = '';
        if (!empty($atts)) {
          foreach($atts as $att) {
            $html .= $att;
          }
        } else {
          $html = '<h3>I have been delayed</h3>';
        }

        $response = [];
        $response['html'] = $html;
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
}
new AjaxShortcode();
```

The Javascript:

```
( function( $ ) {
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        //Perform Ajax request.
        $.ajax({
            url: data.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                action: 'ajax_test'
            },
            success: function( response ) {
              console.log(data.html);
            }
        });
    });
}(jQuery) );
```

This always returns the first

## Initial Output

but then only

#### I have been delayed

Even if I type in the shortcode like this:

[ajax_test att_1="foo" att_2=false att_3=400]

Does the the ajax call trigger a new instance of the object? That would explain why I can't access the variables within getAtts()

Comment: The AJAX call triggers a whole different _request_. It has nothing whatsoever to do with any code that might have run before, or access to any variables that where not persisted somewhere outside of the scope of the original script instance.

Comment: That is what I suspected, but any insight on how to access those parameters in light of that?

Comment: Make the original shortcode output transport the necessary info inside the HTML, so that the AJAX code portion can grab it from there and pass it on with the request it is making …? Put the values into individual custom data attributes, or all together JSON-encoded into a single one, or …

Comment: add_action( "wp_ajax_ajax_test", [ $this, 'ajaxDelayed' ] ); ? this is wrong friend the correct one was for the output I believe

Comment: After an ajax is over you need to die (); at the end of the function

Comment: @04FS thanks. That is a legitimate answer to the problem. Appreciated.

Comment: @KelvinMariano there is a die. The encode is wrapped by it. And the order of action call is correct: the shortcode calls the output and the JS calls the later via a wordpress AJAX call. The ajax all works, the problem was passing the shortcode parameters

Answer (score 0):

I was coming at this from the wrong angle (server-side/PHP) and it worked when I stored the variables in the Javascript side of things.

```
( function( $ ) {
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        var att_1 = data.att_1,
            att_2 = data.att_2,
            att_3 = data.att_3;

        //Perform Ajax request.
        $.ajax({
            url: data.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                action: 'ajax_test',
                att_1: att_1,
                att_2: att_2,
                att_3: att_3
            },
            success: function( response ) {
              console.log(data.html);
            }
        });
    });
}(jQuery) );
```

Works fine.